# How do I refresh a RecyclerView with notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using FirebasDatbase and struggleing to refresh the recyclerview after database has been downloaded.
So what happens is - it loads the recyclerview before data is downloaded makes it a 0 size recyclerview. then i close the recyclerview and open again few seconds after and it loads completely the recyclerview from data

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        getIncomingIntent();
    }

    private void showBranches(final String categoryName) {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Categories");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child(categoryName).getChildren()) {
                    mDishName.add(ds.getValue().toString());
                }
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child(categoryName + "Logos").getChildren()){
                    mImages.add(ds.getValue().toString());
                }
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child(categoryName + "Details").getChildren()) {
                    mDishDetails.add(ds.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }


    public void getIncomingIntent(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("title")){
            String categoryName = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
            showBranches(categoryName);
            initRecyclerView();
        }
    }
    public void initRecyclerView(){
        adapter = new ItemRCVAdapter(mDishName, mImages, mDishDetails, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.forceLayout();
    }
}
```

i expect the recyclerview to reload itself when changing. instead of showing an empty list.

Comment: Have you tried to put the `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onDataChanged` method?

Comment: :D silly me, I had several Activities and tried it on the wrong activity. It work of-course.